# advance NSPredicate queries?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with NSPredicate:

```
NSArray *letters = [[table.Letters componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
NSArray *searched = [[searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i<searched.count-1; i++) 
{
     if([letters[i] intValue] == [searched[i] intValue])
          //return the record
     else
          break;
}
```

Basically what I've done is taken each string, separated by commas, and created an array of integers (they will always be integers) then compared the two as integers rather than strings, in order to make it much faster.

Is there any way to do this with `NSPredicate`? or any way to do it with CoreData?

Apparently None of this matters, it's my Fetch request.

```
-(void)titles:(NSString *)toMatch
{
    // THIS IS ALL SETTING UP THE STRING TO BE MATCHED AGAINST THE DATABASE

    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    lineIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *LabelText =toMatch;
    NSString *compareString = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i<LabelText.length; i++)
    {
        int letter = [LabelText characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *firstLetters;
        if(letter<100)
        {
            firstLetters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
            firstLetters = [blah stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", letter];
        }
        else
            firstLetters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", letter];
        compareString= [compareString stringByAppendingString:firstLetters];
        compareString = [compareString stringByAppendingString:@","];
    }
    //ALL THE WAY UP TO HERE


    //SETTING UP QUERY
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate;

    //CHECKING WHICH TYPE OF SEARCH THE USER HAS SELECTED, MATCHING THE STRING FROM THE BEGINNING OR SEEING IF WHAT THEY SEARCHED ARE PRESENT IN THE FIRST LETTERS OF THE STRING
    if ([defaults boolForKey:@"FLS"])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_letter_start BEGINSWITH %@", compareString];
    else
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_letter_start CONTAINS %@", compareString];

    //SETTING UP REQUEST
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:100];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"gurmukhi", @"shabad_id", nil]];
    NSError *error;

    //FETCHING
    fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (Gurbani *shabad in fetchedObjects)
    {
        [retval addObject:shabad.gurmukhi];
        [lineIDArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", shabad.shabad_id]];
    }
    searchResults = retval;
    [searchResultsTable reloadData];
};
```

And here's the Model:
[image: Anything I'm searching regularly is indexed, including what I'm searching right now.]

Here's the output I get from using the argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`:

```
2013-03-20 16:53:57.316 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZSHABAD t0 WHERE  NSCoreDataStringSearch( t0.ZFIRST_LETTER_START, ?, 8, 0) 
2013-03-20 16:53:59.982 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 2.6653s
2013-03-20 16:53:59.983 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 2.6667s for 92 rows.
2013-03-20 16:53:59.988 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZGURMUKHI, t0.ZSHABAD_ID FROM ZSHABAD t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)   LIMIT 100
2013-03-20 16:54:00.058 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0692s
2013-03-20 16:54:00.059 GurbaniKhoj[955:907] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0717s for 92 rows.
```

I'm brand new to this, so maybe this will help, I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: Have you verified that this is actually faster?

Comment: @TomHarrington I'm honestly not sure, but everywhere I've asked I was told to use integer comparisons rather than string comparisons for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are wasting your time.

```
  NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
  NSArray *letters = [[@",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
  NSArray *searched = [[@",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
  for (int i = 0; i<searched.count-1; i++)
  {
    if([letters[i] intValue] == [searched[i] intValue])
    {

    }
//      NSLog(@"same");
  }

  NSLog(@"ints: %f", [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);

  date = [NSDate date];
  for (int i = 0; i<searched.count-1; i++)
  {
    if([letters[i] isEqualToString:searched[i]])
    {

    }
//      NSLog(@"same");
  }
  NSLog(@"strings: %f", [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

ints: 0.006064

strings: 0.000979

Comment: This is odd, because I'm using this with coreData and for some reason the Fetch takes 3-4 seconds for just about 100 rows. Everywhere else I've asked I was told it was because of string comparisons?

Comment: It's can't possibly take 3 seconds for a hundred of rows if you're making a single fetch request. Drop your fetch request code and related data model in your original post

Comment: My eyes.... I'm sorry Mukhi, but I have no idea what the purpose of your code is. Could you please rephrase your task in words like "need to fetch all entities of type Shabad where "first_letter_start" is equal to the search query"?

Comment: Sorry. Basically What you said. I need to fetch all records where first_letter_start matches the letters typed in the search bar. For whatever reason my friend made the database incredibly awkwardly, and the first_letter_start is in the format ",XXX,XXX,XXX," where XXX is the 3 digit number corresponding to each character.   I just edited it for a bit more clarity

Comment: will this predicate do? ["(first_letter_start CONTAINS ,%@) || (first_letter_start BEGINSWITH %@)", query, query]

Comment: It depends on whether or not the user has an option in settings enabled, that's why I'm using 'NSUserDefaults' in the if statement, If you can select which one you want to use depending on that boolean value, then yes it would.

Comment: no, you're missing the point, this predicate has a comma "," and a query ",%@", which will search for anything that begins with comma + your query, with that you won't need to break your strings to parts

Comment: Oh, yeah, that would work I guess, I'll try it and see if there's any difference.

EDIT: but that's not the problem because I've been using the BEGINSWITH query as the default one. both end up taking up around the same time.

Comment: beginswith will not search for a comma+text, but contains will

Comment: Right, but both go around the same speed, and even with the comma there's no difference